# "route" sub-command does not exits in "ip" command on Cisco 2960-S

Tags: cisco, vlan, ip-routing, cisco-catalyst

I am new to cisco. I'm running a Cisco 2960-S and defined several VLAN on it. I like to use SVI feature and set 192.168.1.254 ip address for interface VLAN 1, 192.168.2.254 for interface VLAN 2 and so on, but I can not ping 192.168.X.254 from the device itself but 192.168.1.254 although I issued `no shut` command on every interface VLAN configuration. I need routing between VLANs.
I had a search and find several results for enabling inter VLAN routing like [this link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/15-2_2_e/configuration/guide/b_1522e_2960_2960c_2960s_2960sf_2960p_cg/b_1522e_2960_2960c_2960s_2960sf_2960p_cg_chapter_0100001.html#task_F224015A3D8D4862B3DD87F062922EF0), but the problem is `route` sub-command of `ip` command does not exists:

```
my-net-dev(config)#ip ?
Global IP configuration subcommands:
  access-list           Named access-list
  accounting-list       Select hosts for which IP accounting information is kept
  accounting-threshold  Sets the maximum number of accounting entries
  accounting-transits   Sets the maximum number of transit entries
  address-pool          Specify default IP address pooling mechanism
  admission             Network Admission Control (NAC)
  alias                 Alias an IP address to a TCP port
  arp                   IP ARP global configuration
  auth-proxy            Authentication Proxy
  default-gateway       Specify default gateway (if not routing IP)
  device                Device tracking
  dhcp                  Configure DHCP server and relay parameters
  dhcp-client           Configure parameters for DHCP client operation
  dhcp-server           Specify address of DHCP server to use
  domain                IP DNS Resolver
  domain-list           Domain name to complete unqualified host names.
  domain-lookup         Enable IP Domain Name System hostname translation
  domain-name           Define the default domain name
  finger                finger server
  flow-aggregation      Configure flow aggregation
  flow-cache            Configure netflow cache parameters
  flow-capture          Capture additional netflow information
  flow-egress           Configure netflow egress
  flow-export           Specify host/port to send flow statistics
  flow-top-talkers      Configure netflow top talkers
  ftp                   FTP configuration commands
  gdp                   Router discovery mechanism
  gratuitous-arps       Generate gratuitous ARPs for PPP/SLIP peer addresses
  host                  Add an entry to the ip hostname table
  host-routing          Enable host-based routing (proxy ARP and redirect)
  hostname              Configure hostname types
  hp-host               Enable the HP proxy probe service
  http                  HTTP server configuration
  icmp                  ICMP options
  igmp                  IGMP global configuration
  local                 Specify local options
  name-server           Specify address of name server to use
  options               IP Options treatment
  port-map              Port to application mapping (PAM) configuration commands
  radius                RADIUS configuration commands
  rcmd                  Rcmd commands
  reflexive-list        Reflexive access list
  scp                   Scp commands
  security              Specify system wide security information
  source                IP source
  source-route          Process packets with source routing header options
  ssh                   Configure ssh options
  sticky-arp            Allow the creation of sticky ARP entries
  subnet-zero           Allow 'subnet zero' subnets
  tacacs                TACACS configuration commands
  tcp                   Global TCP parameters
  telnet                Specify telnet options
  tftp                  tftp configuration commands
  verify                URPF SNMP trap and IP packet header validation commands
```

Also `no switchport` is not working itself and need to put some sub-command after it:

```
my-net-dev(config-if)#no switchport 
% Incomplete command.

my-net-dev(config-if)#no switchport  ?
  access         Set access mode characteristics of the interface
  autostate      Include or exclude this port from vlan link up calculation
  block          Disable forwarding of unknown uni/multi cast addresses
  host           Set port host
  mode           Set trunking mode of the interface
  nonegotiate    Device will not engage in negotiation protocol on this interface
  port-security  Security related command 
  priority       Set appliance 802.1p priority
  protected      Configure an interface to be a protected port
  trunk          Set trunking characteristics of the interface
  voice          Voice appliance attributes
```

The ROM is c2960s-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE8.bin

Comment: Have you enabled ip routing? It is not enabled by default. Just go to `conf t` and then issue a `ip routing` command to enable it first.

Comment: This is my problem that `ip route` command does not work in this mode.    `my-net-dev#conf t`
    `Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z. `
    `my-net-dev(config)#ip routing`
                      ^
   `  % Invalid input detected at '^' marker. `

Comment: What is the output of `show version`? You can find out more information about your version of iso from it. Also post the output `show run`.

Answer (score 1):

The 2960-S is a [layer 2 switch](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-2960-series-switches/product_data_sheet0900aecd80322c0c.html). If you need routing between VLANs, you need a router.

Comment: According to these links, a 2960 switch can do that: https://networklessons.com/switching/intervlan-routing/   http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12-2_55_se/configuration/guide/scg_2960/swipstatrout.html   https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11194156/intervlan-routing-catalyst-2960-s

Comment: I see conflicting information with most sources saying the 2960-S is a layer 2 device and some saying that there's a poor implementation of static rounding and `sdm prefer` in newer software versions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the **software features** of the Switch what options are available.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-2960-s-series-switches/data_sheet_c78-726680.html

> **Software Features**
>
> Cisco Catalyst 2960-S Series Switches are available with the LAN Base
>   and LAN Lite feature sets. LAN Lite models provide reduced
>   functionality and scalability for small deployments with basic
>   requirements.
>
> Note that each switch model is tied to a specific feature level; LAN
>   Lite models cannot be upgraded to the LAN Base feature set.

This article explains the various switching capabilities according to features. [Cisco IOS Software Licenses: What’s What for Layer 2 and Layer 3 Switching – Part 1](http://blogs.cisco.com/enterprise/cisco-ios-software-licenses-what%E2%80%99s-what-for-layer-2-and-layer-3-switching-%E2%80%93-part-1)

> The four common Cisco IOS Software feature licenses for switching are:
>
> - LAN Lite:            Enterprise EntryLevel Layer 2 Switching
> - LAN Base:            Enterprise Access Layer 2 Switching
> - IP Base:             Enterprise Access Layer 3 Switching
> - IP Services:         Advanced Layer 3 Switching

Please check the full article for detail information on each type.